# Laravel 7-Change an URL after clicking Submit

Tags: laravel

I have a URL as follows

`http://localhost/MyLaravel/public/user/5199667639cfc4f5ea624f4c18dbf7e8_qB8EuBjsC8aNEXCjhTtZlVg5LVF4AazaD0DUjaK4ZZbShkWSlo0ZgkzuleBk/username/Sk`

This link redirects the user to a form where the user can change her/his basic details (say in a Form Change Details). When I click Submit in Change Details , a request is to be sent via ajax. But I want to change the URL to `http://localhost/MyLaravel/public/change-user-detailsafter` the Submit is clicked.

But on clicking Submit , the URL that I am redirected to is

`http://localhost/MyLaravel/public/user/5199667639cfc4f5ea624f4c18dbf7e8_qB8EuBjsC8aNEXCjhTtZlVg5LVF4AazaD0DUjaK4ZZbShkWSlo0ZgkzuleBk/username/Sk/change-user-details`

How do I do it?

Here are some codes -

**Script**

```
                        $.ajax({
                           method:'POST',
                          url:'change-user-details',
                          cache: false,
                        processData:true,   //Required
                        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        data:{
                          //data
           }, 
                //more codes here
             }); //ajax ends
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('change-user-details','LoginController@change-user-details');
```

Comment: stop using relative URLs

Comment: @lagbox What does that mean?

Comment: `url:'change-user-details'` ... what is `change-user-details` supposed to refer to?

Comment: @lagbox It is an example, not the real url that I am using in my project

Comment: According to your post route, it would be `url:'/change-user-details',` just give a slash before the path

Comment: @sta That wasn't working. I already checked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative url. A relative file path points to a file relative to the current page.
You neef to call your url from the root, change :

```
url:'change-user-details',
```

to

```
url : '/MyLaravel/public/change-user-detailsafter',
```